# how to make a function that validates fields in a form? php

Tags: php, validation, function

Im having a lot of trouble understanding how user defined functions work in general, but i was wondering if someone can show me an example of a function that validates fields in a form

(for example, a username must be 5-10 characters long and only accepts certain characters...etc)

Can someone please show me an example with a brief explanation of how php reads a user defined function?

Comment: don't restrict the user-name, just for fun, let people use what they want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation -

```
function validateUserName($uname){
  $illegalCharacters = array('!','@','#');

  // first check the length
  $length = strlen($uname);
  if ($length < 5 && $length > 10){
    return false;
  }else{
    // now check for illegal characters
    foreach($illegalCharacters AS $char){
      if (strpos($uname,$char) != -1){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

$userName = "user1905577";
if (validateUserName($username)){
  echo "Valid username!";
}else{
  echo "INVALID username!";
}
```

Lets see what is going on here -

We first use [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to test the length of the username and then iterate over all the illegal characters we defined and use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to see if any appear in the username.

The function's name is `validateUserName` and we can call it by simply placing it's name and brackets afterwards. Like this - `validateUserName()`. This function has to receive a parameter (the username), so we pass that within the brackets, Like this - `validateUserName($username)`

Comment: Thank you I have a few questions...
Why does $illegalCharacters=array what exactly does this mean?

How can i use a Regular expression to test the length of the username?

Comment: @use - `$illegalCharacters` is an array of characters that are  "illegal to use" in a username. I put some random characters in there just as an example.

Comment: With regard to using regular expressions - regex is a powerful tool. You can validate usernames with a regex that checks everything all in one go. However from what I could understand in your question, these were the criteria you were looking for - length and character restriction. There are already native PHP methods and functions that can do exactly what you are looking for in this case, so I didn't feel the need to bring out the big guns. I also feel that it is best to answer a question in the same complexity it was asked so as to not overwhelm the question asker (no offence) :)

Comment: None taken! I am just an eager learner lol I would really appreciate an example of using regrex in the same mannar if you are up for it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @use - The regex you need is `/[[:alnum:]]{5,10}/` (5-10 alpha-numeric characters), but another example is out of the scope of this question. Why don't you [read up](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) on regex and try to implement this one I gave you.

Comment: I think my issue is knowing where in the code to put the regrex, since $length = strlen() ...what would $length = if i am using regrex? if there would be a $length at all in this case

Comment: The length is already in the regex. It's the {5,10}.. Take a look at some examples - there are [many on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+php)... Over 9000!

Comment: oh, right i knew that already! i dont think im asking the right question, sorry. I guess what my question REALLY is, is how do i insert the regex into my php script? where would it be placed in the function?